# how to change the default directories paths in web.xml in the spring project

Tags: spring-mvc

as by default when we run the project the home.jsp file which is in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/ will be called. but if i create a new folder inside WEB-INF say as jsp and put the home.jsp inside it. then how do i give the path in web.xml for the file. say in the servlet-mapping /home  or in controller @RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: It's hard to help with just this information. Are you following a blog post/ tutorial? You may want to take some screenshot & post the content of your web.xml

Comment: as by default when we run the project the home.jsp - actually there are plenty ways to configure with Spring, we don't know the config in your case, so that we won't be able to help efficiently.